# ¿Como puedo cambiar el formato de un DatetimeField en Django?

Tags: python, django, datetime, djangorestframework, python-requests

Estoy trabajando en una API en django-rest para migrar una base de datos que tengo en un CSV a una instancia SQL en la nube de google. El problema, me lanza un error 400 porque el formato de algunas columnas no es el mismo que el que esta en la base de datos. Con la ayuda de pandas ya he logrado introducir algunos campos, pero no los relacionados con fechas.

```
""" MODELS """
class Contrato(models.Model):
    def __init___(self):
        pass
    contrato_numero = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=100)
    acta_inicio = models.DateField()
    hasta = models.DateField()

    objeto_contrato = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    porcentaje_cumplido = models.FloatField()
    fecha_contrato = models.DateField()
    """ son muchos mas campos pero estoy validando estos """
```

```
""" serializers """
class Contratos_serializer(serializers.Serializer):

    contrato_numero = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)
    acta_inicio = serializers.DateField()
    hasta = serializers.DateField()

    objeto_contrato = serializers.CharField(max_length=500)
    porcentaje_cumplido = serializers.FloatField()
    fecha_contrato = serializers.DateField()

    def create(self, data):
        return Contrato.objects.create(**data)
```

```
""" view """
class Introduce_contrato(APIView):
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    # POST API
    def post(self,request):
        serializer = Contratos_serializer(data = request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        contrato = serializer.save()
        return JsonResponse([0], safe=False)
```

Estoy enviando los request con la libreria request de python.

```
response = requests.post(url, data={'contrato_numero': '3.500-1234567', 'acta_inicio':        '2021-01-14', 'hasta': '2021-04-30', 'objeto_contrato': 'PRESTAR LOS SERVICIOS PROFESIONALES COMO ABOGADA EN LA ACTIVIDAD:BRINDAR APOYO EN LAS EMERGENCIAS Y DESASTRES, DENTRO DEL PROYECTO IMPLEMENTACIÓN DEL PROCESO DEL MANEJO DEL DESASTRE EN EL DEPARTAMENTO', 'porcentaje_cumplido': 0.25, 'fecha_contrato': '2021-01-07'},
             headers = {'Authorization': token,
             'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
```

Answer (score 0):

yo te podría sugerir lo siguiente, si te llega la fecha en formato de texto mediante strptime convertirlo a un objeto datetime que es el que maneja django y tu indicandole el formato de fecha que estas recibiendo, te pongo un ejemplo:

```
import datetime

date_time_str = '2018-06-29 08:15:27.243860'
date_time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_time_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

Con lo anterior estas recibiendo tu str '2018-06-29 08:15:27.243860' y en la parte de: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f' estas indicando el formato de fecha y tiempo que estas recibiendo para hacerle el cast a un objeto datetime.

Si solo requieres un objeto date solo dejarias  ''%Y-%m-%d' suponiendo que en ese formato lo estes mandando. Aqui puedes encontrar los formatos aceptados por strftime: https://strftime.org/

Esto lo tendrías que aplicar en donde estés recibiendo tu request para formatearlo previamente antes de asignarlo a un campo.

En DRF que es en tu método validate_campo(self) donde tendrias que acceder a tu campo(cambia campo por el nombre del tuyo) y al valor, seria algo asi:

```
def validate_campo(self, value):
    datetime_str = value
    try:
        date_time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(datetime_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
        # Retornar el valor como datetimeobj y no como str
        return date_time_obj
    except ValueError:
        raise serializers.ValidationError("Formato o fecha incorrecta.")
```